# openseadragon zoom direction

Tags: zooming, openseadragon

I am developing using Openseadragon
When I am zooming in using mouse wheel and reading the value of the current zoom using the function getZoom() , I am getting the value of the zoom for each wheel step

When I keep scrolling the mouse wheel in the up direction the zoom value keep changing normally as expected , going bigger.
But on a direction change of the mouse wheel , going down , ( in the first step only ) the zoom value continue to rise ( getting bigger ) but it should decrease ( getting smaller )

I think it is a bug of the Openseadragon , does anyone can help on the issue ? any info ?

Comment: That's pretty wild! I haven't heard of this happening before. Does it only happen on your site, or also on the OpenSeadragon viewer on http://openseadragon.github.io/? What OS and browser are you using? Is there anything unusual about your mouse?

Answer (score 0):

I would think what you're seeing is because of the spring animation (slowing the zoom change exponentially as the zoom approaches the target level) after each wheel event.

If you use `getZoom(false)` you'll get the target zoom, which should change sign when you change the wheel direction.